# How to prove: If $|z| < \frac{1}{2}$, then $|e^z-1-z| \leq {|z|}^2$?

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

How to prove: If $|z| < \frac{1}{2}$, then $|e^z-1-z| \leq {|z|}^2$?
I need to use this inequality to prove the CLT, the teacher says we can use Taylor expansion to prove it, yet I can only get "$e^z-1-z=\frac{1}{2}z^2+o(z^2)$", and I think there's nowhere I can put the condition $|z| < \frac{1}{2}$ in use.
Thx.

Comment: Do you mean a higher order of $z$ in your Taylor expansion of those terms you are stating as negligible? ("$\omicron(z^2)$")

Comment: @Kevin Sorry, I actually don't know whether I can take modulus on both sides, so I left the equation there.

Comment: How is this related to the central limit theorem?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire It's one of the lemmas for finding the conditions for Lindeburg-Feller Theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that\begin{align}\left\lvert e^z-1-z\right\rvert&=\left\lvert\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\cdots\right\rvert\\&=\lvert z\rvert^2\left\lvert\frac1{2!}+\frac z{3!}+\cdots\right\rvert\\&\leqslant\lvert z\rvert^2\left(\frac1{2!}+\frac1{2\times3!}+\frac1{2^2\times4!}+\cdots\right)\\&\leqslant\frac{\lvert z\rvert^2}2\left(1+\frac1{2\times3}+\frac1{2^2\times3\times4}+\cdots\right)\\&\leqslant\frac{\lvert z\rvert^2}2\left(1+\frac12+\frac1{2^2}+\cdots\right)\\&=\lvert z\rvert^2.\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

[Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor%27s_theorem_in_one_real_variable) with integral remainder for the function $f$ on segment $[0,1]$ at order two leads to:
$$f(1) = f(0) +\frac{f^\prime(0)}{1!}+\int_0^1 \frac{f^{\prime \prime}(t)}{2!} (1-t)^2 \ dt.$$
Using it for $f : t \mapsto e^{tz}$ at order two, we get:
$$\vert e^z - 1 - z \vert \le \left\vert \frac{z^2}{2!} \right\vert\sup\limits_{t \in [0,1]} \left\vert e^{tz}\right\vert \le \left\vert \frac{z^2}{2!} \right\vert e^{\vert z \vert} \le \vert z \vert^2 \frac{e^{\frac{1}{2}}}{2} \le \vert z \vert^2$$

Comment: Sorry, but could you please tell me some more details about the first inequality?

Comment: You can have a look for details at [Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor%27s_theorem_in_one_real_variable).

Comment: I mean I'm confused with your instruction, do you mean do the Taylor expansion on $e^{tz}$ at t=0 with respect to t? I don't think I can get the first inequality directly this way, sorry for my clumsiness.

Comment: I mean applying Taylor's theorem to the map $t \mapsto e^{tz}$ on the segment $[0,1]$.

Comment: You mean at every point in this segment [0,1]? Sorry I never know this, I only now how to do the Taylor expansion at one specific point. Could please show me how to do it? Sorry for bother you, but I really need your help.

Comment: I provided some details in the answer.