# Prove this inequality involving complex numbers and $e$

Tags: complex-analysis

For all $z \in \mathbb{C}, |z| < 1$ prove:

$|e^z-1-z| \leq (e-2)|z|^2$

Now I guess this demands some sort of triangle inequality.
What I tried: $|e^z-1-z|\leq|e^z|+|1|+|z|\leq|e^z|+2$ but I don't think this is the right way. Also since the absolute value of $z$ is less or equal than $1$ I figured that the absolute values of the real and imaginary part of $z$ are less or equal than $1$. Hence I could derive for $z=x+iy$: $|e^{x+iy}|\leq|e^x||e^{iy}|=|e^x||(\cos(y)+i\sin(y))|\leq e|1+i|=\sqrt{2}e$

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3485230/42969

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hint would be "Taylor expansion"

Details are as follows:

$$e^z=1+z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\ldots $$
Thus
$$e^z-1-z=\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\ldots $$
and consequently,
$$|e^z-1-z|=|z^2||(\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{z}{3!}+\ldots)| $$
using $|z|<1$ and the fact that $e=1+1+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}\ldots $, and by adding $2$ and $-2$, we get
$$|e^z-1-z|\leq|z^2|(\underbrace{[1+1+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+\ldots]}_{=e}-2) $$
which implies
$$|e^z-1-z|\leq|z^2|(e-2) .$$